# postfix/dovecot Relay access denien out of sudden (for some virtual hosts)

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

while everything was working, today 3 of 10 domains on my vps Ubuntu server (postfix/dovecot) cant send emails from outlook getting
Relay Access Denied. No changes were done. (all the domains were working normally till today)

```
Mail.log
Oct 24 22:27:43 mail postfix/smtpd[7662]: connect from my.desk.top.ip
Oct 24 22:27:43 mail postfix/smtpd[7662]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused
Oct 24 22:27:44 mail postfix/smtpd[7662]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from my.desk.top.ip: 554 5.7.1 <receipt@email.com>: Relay access denied; from=<info@problematicdomain.com> to=<receipt@email.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<DESKTOPFTP67QJ>
Oct 24 22:27:46 mail postfix/smtpd[7662]: disconnect from my.desk.top.ip
```

Dovecot.log

```
Oct 24 22:27:12 auth: Debug: passwd-file(info@problematicdomain.com,my.desk.top.ip,<pLSYw1BcsgBeQ1jL>): lookup: user=info@problematicdomain.com file=/etc/dovecot/passwd
Oct 24 22:27:12 auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK  1   user=info@problematicdomain.com
Oct 24 22:27:12 auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST 997982209   7658    1   effa60cd62c34b72950ad17e6f08066c    session_pid=7661
Oct 24 22:27:12 auth: Debug: passwd-file(info@problematicdomain.com,my.desk.top.ip,<pLSYw1BcsgBeQ1jL>): lookup: user=info@problematicdomain.com file=/etc/dovecot/users
Oct 24 22:27:12 auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER    997982209   info@problematicdomain.com  uid=5000    gid=5000    home=/var/spool/vmail/problematicdomain.com/
Oct 24 22:27:12 pop3-login: Info: Login: user=<info@problematicdomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=my.desk.top.ip, lip=172.31.1.100, mpid=7661, TLS, session=<pLSYw1BcsgBeQ1jL>
Oct 24 22:27:12 pop3(info@problematicdomain.com): Info: Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/13, size=15495
```

postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

myhostname = mail.servermaindomain.gr
mydestination = mail.servermaindomain.gr, localhost.servermaindomain.gr, localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
#smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
#smtpd_sasl_path = auth/dovecot
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
message_size_limit = 26240000

# DKIM
# --------------------------------------
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Comment: Clearly something was done - possibly not by you, or not knowingly, but something.  I wonder if you are using a VPN and it fell offline (leaving mail to route out the WAN interface on the public IP which is not known to your mail server as being part of your network.  Can you confirm whether you use SMTP AUTH and how you connect to the VPS.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I try to send mail via Outlook ( with checked option -> Required on logon secure password authentication)
with my VPS i connect via ssh.

My client notice the problem (and after testing all the domains i have in the vps i found 3/10 domains now have that problem)